# Which volume formula do I use for this problem?

Tags: calculus, integration

Find the volume generated by revolving about the $x$-axis the region bounded by the curves:

$$f(x)= x^2 ,\ g(x) = 2-x^2.$$

I drew the graph and if we are revolving around the $x$-axis it looks like we are going to have some sort of gap inside part of the shape (washer)?

So I went ahead and got the bounds: $-1,\ +1$.

I'm thinking I should be integrating using this formula:

$$ V = \int_{-1}^{1} \pi [ (g(x)^2 - (f(x))^2 ]\, dx $$

Does that seem correct?

Comment: Not only seems: it is. Just please do edit your post's mathematics (in the integral's line) to make it readable.

Comment: @DonAntonio Thank you for the confirmation. I apologize about the format, how should I be formatting it to make it more readable?

Comment: use \limits after \int to put the limits directly over/under the integral sign, but what I meant is that the upper limit in the original post was off. Now it's been edited and it's fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're "spot on." Your assessment of the problem is correct, as is your integral.

Comment: Awesome! I could also solve this in terms of y, correct? It would be a funky way to slice it, but might be fun to try out.

Comment: That would have been much more complicated, as you'd need to express both functions as functions of y ($x = \cdots$), and then it only gets worse!

Comment: :) my professor is the type to do something like that though! Hope you'll be online for a bit, I will likely have a few more to post.

Comment: It told me to wait to accept the answer :) On the other question, someone answered a few minutes before you. (I have another volume question I'm typing up)

Comment: Not a problem...sort of just teasing you! ;-)